# Mono Develop debugger crashes when passing 2d array to function

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, mono, monodevelop

I'm having problems with debugging mono applications, using mono develop. When I'm trying to debug code inside a function that gets 2d array as a parameter, debugger crashes.
For example then debugger steps inside Test function:

```
float[,] b = new float[4,4];
Test(b);

static void Test(float[,] x)
{
    float[,] y = x;
}
```

I'm getting assertion error:

> Exception in callback: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index Was outside the bounds of array.

Is there something I'm doing wrong with my code, or is there something wrong with mono/monodevelop?

EDIT: Yes, this code is only an example; I was trying to narrow down the problem.

Comment: "Is there something I'm doing wrong with my code, or is there something wrong with mono/monodevelop" - which is more likely? What are you actually trying to do with that float array assignment?

Comment: Is that the *minimal* code to reproduce the behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the Win32 CorDebugger addin in MonoDevelop.

As a workaround, you can install Mono on Windows and target the Mono framework/debugger instead of the Microsoft runtime/debugger and things will work for you.

(The Mono debugger addin is much better maintained)

Comment: Works like a charm! I didn't know monodevelop uses ms .net as default.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with this code, it compiles and runs with Mono debugger just fine.
(I'm using MonoDevelop 3.1.1 on OS X.)

This is the C# program I compiled:

```
using System;

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        float[,] b = new float[4,4];
        Test(b);
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
    }

    static void Test(float[,] x)
    {
        float[,] y = x;
    }
}
```

Also, `TargetInvocationException` indicates that the error occured [from a method invoked through reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception.aspx)—perhaps this is why you missed the actual problem? A stack trace should give you a hint where to look for tha actual exception.
 It may even be in a different thread.

Comment: Well, if it's working for you, I'll have to check it on my another computer then, because it still crashes my debugger. Stacktrace leads me to MonoDebelop.Debugger.Win32.CorDebuggerSession.OnbBeakpoint( )

Comment: @demi: This is obviously a debugger bug. What I do in such case is [file a bug so guys at Xamarin can fix it](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com).

Comment: This is a bug in the Win32 CorDebugger addin. As a workaround, you can install Mono on Windows and target the Mono framework/debugger instead of the Microsoft runtime/debugger and things will work for you.

Comment: @jstedfast: Works like a charm! I didn't know monodevelop uses ms .net as default.

Comment: @jstedfast: Can you please post your comment as an answer so the OP could accept it?